# Button event with value from xml and java code

Tags: android, android-layout

There are four edit text boxes already placed via XML and other can two in a row can be added by clicking plus button. below it.

Now, I have button name calculate in which I want to assign event which will be related to the value stored in these edit text boxes.

So like

```
<edit text1> <edit text2> 
< edit text3> <edit text4>
<edit text 5> <edit text6>
```

In both of these I will enter some value and lets say I want to do

```
((edit text1)*(edit text2))+((edittext3)*(edit text4))+((edittext5)*(edit text6))
```

and this event should be done when I click calculate.  I know how to do button click event as you can see I have done that.  I need help in parsing these values into the calculator click event.  Even the values going in edit text boxes from XML and the one that are getting generated by the plus button.

Also, I want to change the layout a bit.  I tried to play around with it, but now I managed to get the buttons below the edit text boxes but when I click plus + button edit boxes come below, whereas I want them to come to the top?  Like the layout of the edit text I have above.

Java code:

```
import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

    public class PlusbuttonActivity extends Activity 
    implements OnClickListener  {

        private TextView tt;
        private TextView j;
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        private LinearLayout root;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            View btnButton = findViewById(R.id.button_next);
            Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            mButton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

             tt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tt);
             j=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.j);

             root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
             mButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              switch (v.getId()) {
                 case R.id.button:
                 View view = doStuff();
                  addViewToRoot(view);
                break;
                 case R.id.button_next:
                     View view1 = doCalc();
                     addViewToRoot(view1);
                     break;

              }
            }

          private View doCalc() {
                // but these are text boxes.. i want to implement the edit boxes and output the result in text box
              int parsedInt = Integer.parseInt(tt.getText().toString());
              int parsedIn = Integer.parseInt(j.getText().toString());




                return null;
            }

        private View doStuff() {  
                EditText t = new EditText(PlusbuttonActivity.this);
                t.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                t.setWidth(250);
                EditText a = new EditText(PlusbuttonActivity.this);
                a.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                a.setWidth(250);
                LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(PlusbuttonActivity.this);

                t.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                // t.setBackgroundColor(0xffCECECE);


                a.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                l.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                l.addView(t);
                l.addView(a); 

                return l; 


        }          

        private void addViewToRoot(View v){
          root.addView(v);
        }

    }
```

XML file:

```
      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:orientation="vertical"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:id="@+id/linearLayout">


    <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 >

            <TextView  
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Units"
                android:id="@+id/tt"
                />
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:gravity="right" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:text="Grades"
            android:id="@+id/j"></TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" 
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:orientation="horizontal">

              <EditText 
                android:layout_width="250px"     
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
                android:id="@+id/edLat">
              </EditText>

              <EditText     
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
                android:id="@+id/edLong" android:layout_width="150dp">
               </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" 
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:orientation="horizontal">

              <EditText 
                android:layout_width="250px"     
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
                android:id="@+id/et2">
              </EditText>

              <EditText     
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
                android:id="@+id/et1" android:layout_width="150dp">
               </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/button" android:text="+" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></Button>

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button_next"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="CALCULATE"
    >
    </Button>
    </RelativeLayout>



    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please make jj,t,root private

Comment: may I also suggest, that your Activity should implement the OnClickListener interface - you code will be cleaner this way.

Comment: umm... can u edit the code i m not able to catch this?

Comment: sure...I did some changes. Commented out some parts of the previous code.

Comment: now it just crashes.. 
can you edit it here on my code.... 

and also for the button thing.. i dont get how i m right the arthematice term for paramlayout edit text and edit text from xml

Comment: i edited the code now.. please help :$

Comment: if you have trouble with the code now, you should revert to your previous version.

Comment: umm... i m still confuse on how to do that arthmetic for the calc function.. i can parse the edit text for xml.. but what about the ones which are getting dynamically generated by click button..

i really wana get this done..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not completely sure you understand the current code.

1. In this code section:

   ```
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
         switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button:
            View view = doStuff();
             addViewToRoot(view);
           break;
            case R.id.button_next:
                View view1 = doCalc();
                addViewToRoot(view1);
                break;
         }
       }
   ```

Why are you calling addViewToRoot for "button_next" ? 
Don't you want the results to be shown in another Activity?
You should use:

```
                 case R.id.button_next:
                 startActivity(new Intent(this, YourShowCalcResultsActivity.class));
                 break;
```

1. I think you should consider using [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) to achieve inserting those layout elements at the top. Briefly the steps are: Wrap the LinearLayout you create in doStuff() in RelativeLayout. You need to have the parent Layout also to be RelativeLayout.
   Than you can use [addRules()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#addRule%28int,%20int%29) and align the elements as you like.
  3.

Comment: i want to implement them in same class.. not different class :$

Comment: you want everything in the same Activity? Where do you display the calculations?

Comment: I got how to get the xml values like u should me for the edit text.. but what about the ones that are being generated with the click button...

Comment: What do you mean - Window? Is this a screen or Activity? If it's a screen, you can use different Activities. If it's the same Activity, I have not seen in your layout an element, that you will use to display the Calculations.

Comment: The once that are generated with the click button - you should assign them IDs and retrieve them later, exactly as you retrieve the already created once.

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I understand correctly. You want to parse a number from each EditText so you can perform arithmetic on them...

First, get a reference to the EditText. If the EditText was made in XML, be sure you assigned it an id and use

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editID);
```

If the EditText was made in code, you should already have a reference to it, so there's no need to use findViewById.

To parse an int from an EditText:

```
int parsedInt = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
```

To parse a double from an EditText:

```
Double.parseDouble(et.getText().toString());
```

To parse a float:

```
Float.parseFloat(et.getText().toString());
```

Once you parse the numbers using whatever type you want, arithmetic is easy.

Comment: ye but this can i do it from the edit text for xml... but what about the ones that are getting generating by + button clicked in java?

Comment: You can do this for any EditText, regardless of whether it was made in XML or in code, as long as you have a reference to it.

Comment: // modified
     amount1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);
    
     amount2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2);

     Button button_next=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_next);
       button_next.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
       {public void onClick
       (View  v) { calculate();}

  private void calculate() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   Double.parseDouble(amount1.getText().toString());
   Double.parseDouble(amount2.getText().toString());
  }});
   }
     // modified
 
i tried this.. gives me error on other button fuction please help..

Comment: I assume the error is "cannot refer to a non-final variable amount1 inside an inner class defined in a different method"? If that's the case, you can declare amount1 and amount2 as final variables (e.g., "final EditText amount1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);" )